# Which type of conjugacy class of $SL(2,5)$ includes $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3\\ 3 & 3\end{pmatrix}?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I'm trying out a bunch of calculations to better understand [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4765774/104041) (where $\mathcal{F}=\Bbb F_q$ is finite field, $q$ is a power of a prime):

> We can describe the matrix representatives of conjugacy classes in $\mathcal{S}=SL(2,\mathcal{F})$ by four families of types ([6]):
>
> 1. $\begin{pmatrix} r & 0 \\ 0 & r\end{pmatrix}$, where $r\in\mathcal{F}$ and $r^2=1$.
> 2. $\begin{pmatrix} r & 0 \\ 0 & s\end{pmatrix}$, where $r,s\in\mathcal{F}$ and $rs=1$.
> 3. $\begin{pmatrix} s & u \\ 0 & s\end{pmatrix}$, where $s\in\mathcal{F}, s^2=1$ and $u$ is either $1$ or a non-square element of $\mathcal{F}$, *i.e.* $u\in \mathcal{F}\setminus\{ x^2: x\in \mathcal{F}\}$.
> 4. $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & w\end{pmatrix}$, where $w=r+r^q$ and $1=r^{1+q}$ for some $r\in \mathcal{E}\setminus\mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{E}$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathcal{F}$.
>
> That is, any conjugacy class $A^\mathcal{S}$ of $\mathcal S$ must contain one of the above matrices.

This is from Harris *et al.*'s, *"On Conjugacy Classes of $SL_2(q)$."*

### The Question:

> Which type of conjugacy class  of $SL(2,5)$ (*i.e*, 1., 2., 3., or 4.) includes
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 & 3\\
> 3 & 3
> \end{pmatrix}?$$

The matrix is, of course, taken modulo five.

### Context:

I used GAP to compute the conjugacy classes, like so:

```
gap> ConjugacyClasses(SL(2,5));
[ [ [ Z(5)^0, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^0 ] ]^G,
[ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2 ], [ Z(5)^0, Z(5)^3 ] ]^G,
[ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^3 ], [ Z(5)^3, Z(5)^3 ] ]^G,
[ [ Z(5)^2, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2 ] ]^G,
[ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2 ], [ Z(5)^0, Z(5) ] ]^G,
[ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^3 ], [ Z(5)^3, Z(5) ] ]^G,
[ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2 ], [ Z(5)^0, Z(5)^2 ] ]^G,
[ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^2 ], [ Z(5)^0, Z(5)^0 ] ]^G,
[ [ Z(5)^3, 0*Z(5) ], [ 0*Z(5), Z(5) ] ]^G ]
gap> x:=[[0*Z(5), Z(5)^3],[Z(5)^3, Z(5)^3]];
[ [ 0*Z(5), Z(5)^3 ], [ Z(5)^3, Z(5)^3 ] ]
gap> Display(x);
 . 3
 3 3
gap>
```

I think I have all the others classified; respectively:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\text{Matrix} & \text{1, 2, 3, or 4 as above}\\
\hline
I & 1.\\
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 3
\end{pmatrix} & 4.\\
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 3\\
3 & 3
\end{pmatrix} & ?\\
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} & 1.\\
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix} & 4.\\
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 3\\
3 & 2
\end{pmatrix} & 3?\\
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} & 4.\\
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} & 4.\\
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} & 2.
\end{array}$$

As you can see, I can't use the process of elimination (as every type is accounted for above). That's kind of cheating anyway.

I doubt it's 3., since $3^2\pmod 5\equiv -1\not\equiv 1$.

I get the feeling I'm missing something obvious.

There'll be at least one way to use GAP for this but I'm interested in computing it by hand, so as to enable understanding.

---

Edit: I just realised I miscalculated for

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 3\\
3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Hence "3?" in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is $x^2-3x-9 = x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$.

Since it is not central, it must have type 3 with $s= -1$

It is not too hard to triangularize it by hand, but a quick computer calculation shows that we can take $u=2$ or 3 .

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial of matrices of type 1 is $(t-r)^2$, with minimal polynomial $(t-r)$ (and they are central, so they are only conjugate to themselves). The characteristic polynomial for matrices of type $2$ is $(t-r)(t-s)$. The characteristic polynomial of matrices of type $3$ is $(t-r)^2$ with minimal polynomial $(t-r)^2$. The characteristic polynomial of matrices of type $4$ is $t^2-wt+1 = (t-r)(t-r^q)=(t-r)(t-r^{-1})$, which by choice of $r$ is irreducible over $\mathcal{F}$.

So all you need is the characteristic polynomial to know which type you are in, and whether the matrix is not diagonal. For your initial matrix the characteristic polynomial is $(t+1)^2$ and is not diagonal, so it is type $3$. Your corrected matrix has characteristic polynomial $(t-1)^2$ and is not diagonal, so again it is of type $3$.